# Nearby icon no longer illuminates and Nearby app doesn't show notification

Tags: ibeacon, beacon, eddystone, google-nearby

I successfully registered a beacon using the Beacon Tools app and received a Nearby notification on multiple occasions after setting them up in the Beacon Dashboard https://developers.google.com/beacons/dashboard/

I removed and added several different Nearby notifications while testing different ones and url's and now the notification have stopped completely.
The Nearby icon in the app drawer no longer illuminates and the Nearby App does not show any links either.

My questions is if anyone is having this same issue and is there a way to deregister the beacon and start over?

Please advise...thanks

Comment: Can you try on a second phone?

Comment: I have an iOS test device with Chrome installed and it's looking for Physical Web objects, but I'm not sure I should see the Nearby notifications.  I'm looking for another Android device.  Currently, I am at a 'live' customers site that only had iBeacon turned on.  We're just learning how to setup the Eddystone.

Comment: If you can change the beacon identifier, you can try registering that as a new beacon and setting up a new Nearby notification for it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately that didn't work. smh

Comment: Can your Android device see the beacon at all?  Try my Locate app here: https://www.google.com/search?q=locate+beacon+android&oq=locate+beacon+android&aqs=chrome..69i57.5496j0j4&client=ms-android-google&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Cool app...Yes, I can see the beacon

Comment: Unfortunately that means it is not an issue with your phone detecting BLE, and not an issue with your beacon, so it must be an issue with either Google Play Services on the phone, or with the Nearby registration on the server.  I would still try a second phone if you have one.  If you can share a beacon identifier to test I am happy to do so for you.

Comment: I think we have figured out the issue.  We were using goo.gl to shorten our url.  The shortened url was a https link but our site was not.  We have since updated our url's and it seems to work fine.